# Keeping Backslash Escaped Single Quote in Bash EOD for Expect

Tags: bash

I've tried hard to find an answer that helps me with this problem, but I can't figure out how to send a backslash through to an expect statement. Below is my code. When it attempts to execute the ssh statement, it never has the backslash before the single quote I need.

```
#!/bin/bash
CLUSTER_NAME=examplecluster
SAMPLE_N=100
REP_N=1

declare -a sparr=('Wilson'"\'"'s_Warbler')

for sp in "${sparr[@]}"
do
RUN_NAME=${sp}_${SAMPLE_N}_${REP_N}
cd /home/shared/stemhwf/stem_hwf/runs/${RUN_NAME}/data

/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
set timeout -1
spawn ssh hdiuser@${CLUSTER_NAME}-ssh.azurehdinsight.net "mkdir -p /home/hdiuser/${RUN_NAME}"
expect password: { send "XXXXXXXX"; exp_continue }
EOD
done
```

This always produces the following:

```
spawn ssh hdiuser@examplecluster-ssh.azurehdinsight.net mkdir -p /home/hdiuser/Wilson's_Warbler_100_1

bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How do I keep the backslash in the ssh expect statement?

Comment: I know that including the backslash works, because I've tested it manually from the command line. 

`ssh hdiuser@examplecluster-ssh.azurehdinsight.net "mkdir -p /home/hdiuser/Wilson\'s_Warbler_100_1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add three slashes before the single quote when declaring the array:

`declare -a sparr=("Wilson\\\'s_Warbler")`

Also put escaped double quotes around your destination path, so:

```
spawn ssh hdiuser@${CLUSTER_NAME}-ssh.azurehdinsight.net "mkdir -p \"/home/hdiuser/${RUN_NAME}\""
```